# Where can I learn to pronounce Revised Romanization of Korean

Tags: pronunciation, romanisation

I am a starter for learning Korean.

From these two websites: 
 1) https://www.wattpad.com/37798905-learn-korean-language-reading-romanized-korean

[image: example1] 
,and, 
2) https://lifeoutsideoftexas.com/2014/05/20/how-to-pronounce-korean-words-without-learning-hangul/

[image: example2] 
I learn that romanization and pronunciation are not the same.

Where can I find a comprehensive resource that teaches how to pronounce these Romanised Korean in English? My purpose is for travelling in Korean, for a short period, not for a long stay. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Korean How about this one? RR means Revised Romanization.

Comment: In South Korea, you can take advantage of fast Internet speeds. I mean, you can just use a mobile application called Papago ([App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/naver-papago-ai-translator/id1147874819) or [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.naver.labs.translator)) to hear the sounds of Korean characters that you see. In my opinion, its TTS engine is not perfect but far better than what Google Translate has. As for the map, KakaoMap is better than any other applications if you are not going to drive a car.

Comment: If it is just for traveling, it’s better to to put your time on remembering phrases than caring about the slightest details on pronunciation.